# Angular 7: core.js:12501 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:

Tags: angular

Hi In my code i am navigating to different html page when i get a reply from my Server.All the things are working fine before i updating my angular version 5 to 7. After version upgradation same code is throwing the below error.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'uploads/dockerExcecutionDependency/vnc.html'
>   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'uploads/dockerExcecutionDependency/vnc.html'
>       at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1765)
>       at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:1730)
>       at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:34)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:79)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:59)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:79)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:59)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:79)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:59)
>       at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:61)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
>       at zone.js:873
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:14051)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>   at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)

Please find my component code which i am sending the url to my html after getting reply from the server

```
    ngOnInit() {
              this.dockerIpPort();
             }
    ///////////////////////
   dockerIpPort()
   {
    var objDocker={};
    objDocker["ipAddress"]="192.168.99.100";
    objDocker["vncPort"]="32768";
    objDocker["vncPassword"]="secret";
    this.servicekey.dockerIpPortServiceCall(objDocker).subscribe(
        result => {
            let url = "/uploads/dockerExcecutionDependency/vnc.html"
            this.dockerPath09 = 
   this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
            document.getElementById("activateDockerButton").click();
        });
 }//dockerIpPort
```

html code where i am using the url to navigation.

```
        <div>
              <div class = "modal fade" id = "myModal04">
                  <div class = "modal-dialog modal-lg">
                     <div class = "modal-content docker">
                          <div class="modal-footer dockerFooter">
                              <p>Close</p>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dockerClose" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></button>
                          </div>
                        <div  class = "modal-body dockerbody">
                          <iframe [src]="dockerPath09"  height="100%" width="100%">
                              <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
                            </iframe>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- myModal04 -->
```

Please Suggest me a better approach to fix this Error. Thanks in Advance

please Find app.module.ts file

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { FileDropModule } from 'ngx-file-drop';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';
    import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
    import { ProjectDetailComponent } from './pDetail.component';
    import { LoginServiceComponent } from './login.service';
    import { ProjectSelectionServiceComponent } from 
    './projectSelection.service';
    import { SelectionComponent } from './projectSelection.component';
    import { ModuleComponent } from './module.component';
    import { FeatureComponent } from './featurePage.component';
    import { TestExecutionComponent } from './testExecution.component';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform- 
    browser/animations';
    import {apiServiceComponent} from './apiService';
    import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { ObjectComponent } from './object.component';
    import { PageNameComponent } from './pageName.component';
    import { ObjectNameComponent } from './objectName.component';
    import { ObjectServiceComponent } from './object.service';
    import { CaptureLabComponent } from './captureLab.component';
    import { ImportProjectComponent } from './importProject.component';
    import { ModuleServiceComponent } from './modulePage.service';
    import { FeatureServiceComponent } from './featurePage.service';
    import { ImportComponent } from './importPage.component';
    import { ImportServiceComponent } from './importPage.service';
    import { ProjectDetailServiceComponent } from './pDetail.service'
    import { AmazingTimePickerModule } from 'amazing-time-picker';
    import { ScriptImportComponent } from './script-import/script- 
    import.component';
    import { EditComponent } from './edit/edit.component';
    import { CreateTestCaseComponent } from './create-test-case/create- 
    test- 
    case.component';
    import { ReportComponent } from './report/report.component';
    import { ObjectCreationComponent } from './object-creation/object- 
    creation.component';
    import { CreateReusableFunctionComponent } from './create-reusable- 
    function/create-reusable-function.component'; // this line you need
    import{ CreatesuiteComponent }  from './createsuite.component';
    import { ExecutionComponent } from './execution.component';
    import { AIComponent } from './ai/ai.component';
    import { TestCaseCommonService } from './test-case-common.service'
    import { NewCreateTestCaseComponent } from './new-create-test- 
    case/new-create-test-case.component';
    import { Ng2GoogleChartsModule } from 'ng2-google-charts';
    import { SuitelevelComponent } from 
    './suitelevel/suitelevel.component';
   import { FeatureLevelComponent } from './feature-level/feature- 
   level.component';
  import { ScriptLevelComponent } from './script-level/script- 
  level.component';
  import { StepLevelComponent } from './step-level/step-level.component'; 
  import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-chartjs';
  import { ExecutionService } from './service/execution.service';
  import {GraphReportService} from './service/graph-report.service';  
  import {ShContextMenuModule} from 'ng2-right-click-menu';

    const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'ImportPage', component: ImportComponent },
    { path: 'createProject', component: ImportProjectComponent },
    {path: '', component: ProjectDetailComponent,
    children: [
    { path: 'CreateModule', component: ModuleComponent },
    { path: 'CreateFeature', component: FeatureComponent },
    { path: 'importComponent', component: ImportComponent },
    { path: 'editComponent', component: EditComponent },
    { path: 'createTestCaseComponent', component: CreateTestCaseComponent 
    },
    { path: 'captureLabComponent', component: CaptureLabComponent },
    { path: 'testExcecutionComponent', component: TestExecutionComponent 
    },
    { path: 'reportComponent', component: ReportComponent },
    { path: 'objectCreationComponent', component: ObjectCreationComponent 
    },
    { path: 'objectRepository', component: ObjectComponent },
    {path: 'createReusableFunction', component: 
    CreateReusableFunctionComponent },
    {path: 'createsuitecomponent' ,component: CreatesuiteComponent},
    { path: 'executionComponent', component: ExecutionComponent },
    { path: 'Artificialpath', component: AIComponent },
    {path:'suitelevel',component:SuitelevelComponent},
    {path:'featurelevel',component:FeatureLevelComponent},
    {path:'scriptlevel',component:ScriptLevelComponent},
    {path:'steplevel',component:StepLevelComponent},
    { path: 'NewCreateTestCaseComponent', component: 
    NewCreateTestCaseComponent,
    children: [
    {
     path:'check',component:StepLevelComponent
    }
    ]
    }
    ]
    },
    { path: 'projectSelection', component: SelectionComponent },
    { path: 'logincomponent', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'createsuitecomponent', component: CreatesuiteComponent },
    { path: 'executionComponent', component: ExecutionComponent },
    ];
```

Comment: could you share your routing code?

Comment: i update the question please find my routings

Comment: Where is the route for the `uploads` url you are trying to access?

Comment: "/uploads/dockerExcecutionDependency/vnc.html" is the path which i want to navigate and  it is stored in my project folder